# EntityFrameworkCore 7 SetProperty(avar,avalue) Unable to cast object of type 'TypedParameterExpression' to type 'LambdaExpression'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

1. Visual Studio 2022
2. .NET 7.0
3. ASP.NET Core Web API Project
4. OS Windows10
5. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.9

**My code:
1.Error**

```
ADal aDal = new ADal();

Func<AModel, float> p = property => property.Balance;

aDal._databaseContext
.ModelDbSet
.Where(w => w.ID == 5)
.Take(1)
.ExecuteUpdate(e => e.SetProperty(p, 636));
```

Out error (Almost no answer found online):

> 引发的异常:“System.InvalidCastException”(位于 System.Private.CoreLib.dll 中)
> “System.InvalidCastException”类型的未经处理的异常在 System.Private.CoreLib.dll 中发生
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

**2.Normal (Do not use : Func<AModel, float> p = property => property.Balance;)**

```
ADal aDal = new ADal();

aDal._databaseContext
.ModelDbSet
.Where(w => w.ID == 5)
.Take(1)
.ExecuteUpdate(e => e.SetProperty(p => p.Balance, 636));
```

I try Expression<Func<AssetModel, float>> p = property => property.Balance; and p.Compile(),But the result is the same,i need help.

Comment: Maybe you need dynamic update based on field name and field value?

Answer (score 0):

This would not be that easy, you will need to work with [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) to build the `SetPropertyCalls` dynamically. Something to get you started:

```cs
Expression<Func<AModel, int>> propExpr = entity => entity.Balance;
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SetPropertyCalls<AModel>));

// find method SetProperty(Func<T, TProp>, TProp):
var method = typeof(SetPropertyCalls<AModel>)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(info => info.Name == nameof(SetPropertyCalls<AModel>.SetProperty))
    // filter out SetProperty(Func<T, TProp>, Func<T, TProp>) overload
    .Where(info => info.GetParameters() is [_, { ParameterType.IsConstructedGenericType: false }]) 
    .Single();

// construct appropriately typed generic SetProperty
var makeGenericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(propExpr.Type.GetGenericArguments()[1]);

var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(param, makeGenericMethod, propExpr, Expression.Constant(636));

// construct final expression
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<SetPropertyCalls<AModel>, SetPropertyCalls<AModel>>>(methodCallExpression, param);
lambdaExpression.Compile();

// use it
ctx.Entities.ExecuteUpdate(lambdaExpression);
```

`Func<AModel, float> p = property => property.Balance;` makes your code compile but EF Core needs an expression tree to translate the code into SQL query and from EF Core perspective `p` is a blackbox which can't be analyzed.

**UPD**

If there is no limitation on `p` type you can also just declare the `Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<AModel>, SetPropertyCalls<AModel>>>` and let the compiler build the expression:

```
Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<AModel>, SetPropertyCalls<AModel>>> p = e => e.SetProperty(a => a.Balance, 636);
```

And pass it to the `ExecuteUpdate` call - `ExecuteUpdate(p)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I also used other methods

Comment: @Allen what do you mean by "other methods"?

Comment: Like this:

`ADal aDal = new ADal();

Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<AModel>, SetPropertyCalls<AModel>>> e = e => e.SetProperty(p => p.Balance, 636);

aDal._databaseContext
.ModelDbSet
.Where(w => w.ID == 5)
.Take(1)
.ExecuteUpdate(e);`

Comment: @Allen yes, of course you can declare the `Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<MyEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<MyEntity>>>` from the get go, the code was written from assumption that you need to work with func/expression in the declared form. Updated answer to incorporate that.