# EF Core: how to give the property for ExecuteUpdate from function parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a scenario where I want to have dynamic property updates.

I have something like an edit dialog in my frontend, and whenever the user interacts with any element I'm updating the related property in my database.

Or at least I'm intending to do so.

Parameter-wise the build process is going through but on compilation I'm getting an error

> Cannot convert between TypedParameterExpression and LambdaExpression

Code:

```cs
public async Task UpdatePropertyAsync<T>(string hash,
    Func<MusicModel, T> property, T value)
{
    await _context.Music
                  .IgnoreAutoIncludes()
                  .Where(x => x.Hash == hash)
                  .ExecuteUpdateAsync(x => x.SetProperty(property, value));
}
```

This method doesn't even take an expression, so it can only be the EF Core logic.

Comment: Try using `Expression<Func<MusicModel, T>>` and see if it works?

Comment: it can't work because the SetPropertyCalls do not even accept an Expression

Comment: for completion: i already tried passing an Expression and then compiling it, just in case. obvisouly that also didn't work.

Comment: My bad, brains stroke, missed out on your last line. One thing I noticed is that MSDN uses `(x => x.SetProperty(x => x.XXX, value)` instead. From [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76628860/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-setpropertycalls-for-executeupdate-in-ef-7) It seems using `Func` as first argument generally leads to this same exception.

Comment: If you know the property names on runtime, I'd suggest setting the value locally by name in a loop and then SaveChanges back. Albeit much longer code will be produced, It's more controllable.

Comment: that would be a nice workaround. but right now the model is not tracked, so i need to make all of my models tracked by default where i want to have this logic... 

i think if i track it later the change detection will not work and it will update the whole thing right?

Comment: Does specifying the type in ExecuteUpdateAsync<T> help?

Comment: sadly not :( ...

Comment: Looks like you can't have generic functions like that for SetProperty. Here's a duplicate question with an answer how it could be done instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762602/entityframeworkcore-7-setpropertyavar-avalue-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-ty

Comment: okay i wish i'd have read that before i tried it by my own because expression api really makes your brain melt :D but it looks like we arrived at a simliar approach.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a ticket in EFCore for resolving this and apparently the only way is to manually compose my own expression... which was... incredibly annoying.

Ticket: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31946

code:

```cs
public async Task UpdatePropertyAsync<TProperty>(Guid id,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> property, TProperty value)
{
var setParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>), "x");

var method = typeof(SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "SetProperty").ElementAt(1);
var call = Expression.Call(
    setParameter,
method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TProperty)),
property,
Expression.Constant(value));

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>>(
    call,
setParameter);

await _context.Entity
    .IgnoreAutoIncludes()
    .Where(...)
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync<TEntity>(lambda);
}
```

can it be any more complicated?

i'm of course only a dumbster when it comes to Expression API, if you have a more pretty solution, feel free to share it.

Comment: Those methods ignore your context and directly access the database. While this is something that is very helpful for large mass updates, if you want to continue with your context for normal EF work, you will sooner or later get errors, because you undermine the change tracking it does.

Comment: It might be easier to get the database entity object manually, modify it using expressions (or maybe reflection) and then save it back.

Comment: that's right, for the better or the worse, i'm not using anything that relies on the change tracking.
i also thought about making it like you proposed, but currently i'm not using any tracking so i would need to come up with a strategy... i guess getting thousands of data sets as a tracked entity is not that much of a good idea huh?